# Memory size exhaused while putting data into array

Tags: php, arrays, json, memory

I'm trying to get Data from Database and store it into a JSON file. 
The script below works fine, but larger Datatables do not work:

```
# SELECT Data from Table
$query = "SELECT `Row1`, 
                 `Row2`, 
                 `Row3`
          FROM   `Table`";
$result = $mysqli->query( $query );

# Declare array 
$data = array();

# Put Data into array
while ( $row = $result->fetch_assoc() ) {
  $data[] = $row;
}

# Put Data into JSON
$JSONData = json_encode( $data, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT );
```

**But larger tables won't work**: 
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 104857600 bytes exhausted.

The Error occours in segment "Put Data into array" (see Code above).

***Are there any other ways to get data into JSON?***

Comment: Increase memory size allowed for PHP in *php.ini* file.

Comment: Use something like a [streaming json encoder](https://github.com/violet-php/streaming-json-encoder).... but don't try to format it PRETTY_PRINT on the server

Comment: The problem is not in ways of getting data into JSON, you have too much data. Do you really need all data in memory at the same time?

Comment: I need to transfer a large table from Server A to Server B and I thought, JSON could do a good job.

Comment: Transfer it piece by piece? Thousand records at a time or something and then again

Comment: Transfer it via a database dump

Comment: piece by piece is a good idea. I'll try it.

Answer (score 0):

Further to Mark Baker's response here's an temporary solution to streaming to json:

```
# SELECT Data from Table
$query = "SELECT `Row1`, 
             `Row2`, 
             `Row3`
      FROM   `Table`";
$result = $mysqli->query( $query );

header("Content-Type: application/json");
echo "[";
# Put Data into array
$first = true;
while ( $row = $result->fetch_assoc() ) {
      echo (!$first?",":"").json_encode($row);
      $first = false;
}
echo "]";
die();
```

Now here's the catch. You cannot put the data in an array or a string, you can only transmit it. In addition, if you're using output buffering (with `ob_start`) you will still run out of memory.